# Using a for loop to add up to a number to the point where it is a multiple of (number % 4 == 0) another number?

Tags: javascript, modulus

I wish to detect when a number is a multiple of 4. When it is not I was thinking of using a for loop to add up to that number till it is a multiple of 4. So something like this(in javascript):

```
if (number % 4 !== 0) {
  for (var i=0;<confused about what condition to put here>; i+=1) {
    if ((number + i) % 4 == 0) {
      return number += i;   // Return the new number
    }
  }
}
```

So, I want to increase a number that is not a multiple of 4 till it is a multiple of 4.

Comment: why don't you add `4 - (number % 4)` to it ?

Comment: You first have to define the range, from where should your loop start, and where should it end? otherwise any loop will keep on going for soooo long to infinity

Comment: As Ofiris said in his answer, you better not use loop for that. While in the case of finding next multiple of 4 it's not such performance drain, image how many additional operation would it took if you wanted to find multiples of 1000 or 1000000 for instance. It all can be solved using two operations in one line as seen in our answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this going to solve your problem?

```
if (number%4 !==0) {
 number += 4 - (number%4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you change the  loop condition to be `i < 4` it should work.

But as I mentioned in comments, you better use `number + (4 - (number % 4))` without using the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of the `modulo` operator.

```
var mod = number % 4;

if (mod !== 0)
    number += (4 - mod);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var someRandomNumber = 9;

console.log('Numbers original value: ' + someRandomNumber);

function makeDivisibleByFour(number) {
    while (number % 4 !== 0)
        number++;
    return number;
}

someRandomNumber = makeDivisibleByFour(someRandomNumber);

console.log('Numbers new value: ' + someRandomNumber);
```